# WITH Clause Syntax error - While using Outer select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have created a sql which is below, when i am trying to put this under outer select which will l just display the results that are rendered from below WITH clause query  it is giving me error in sql server, where as working fine with Oracle.
I don't want to create a view i want to put this below ouptut in merge statement...

```sql
select custno, slipno, category, donation, unique_nm from
( 
-- Here it is throwing error
with  got_debit_custno (custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno)  as
(
    select  custno, slipno, category, donation
    ,   case
          when category = 'CREDIT'
          then 'N/A'
          else custno
        end
    from    a
)
,  prep (custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno, rn, rdt) as
(
    select  dc.*
    ,   row_number ()  over (partition by debit_custno, category order by donation, slipno)
    ,       sum (donation) over (partition by debit_custno, category order by donation, slipno)
    from    got_debit_custno dc
)
,  r (custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno, rn, rdt, mn) as
(
    select  custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno
    ,       case
            when rn = max(rn) over (partition by debit_custno, category)
            then rn
        end
    ,       rdt, 1
    from    prep
    where   rdt <= 27000 or rn = 1
 union all
    select  p.custno, p.slipno, p.category, p.donation, p.debit_custno
    ,       case
            when p.rn = max(p.rn) over (partition by p.debit_custno, p.category)
            then p.rn
        end
    ,       p.rdt, r.mn + 1
    from    prep p
    join    r    on  p.debit_custno = r.debit_custno
             and p.category = r.categoRy
             and p.rn > r.rn
                         and (p.rdt <= r.rdt + 27000 or p.rn = r.rn + 1)
)
select    custno, slipno, category, donation
,         dense_rank () over (order by debit_custno, category, mn) as unique_nm
from      r)
order by  custno, unique_nm, donation
```

Comment: `WITH` goes at the start of your statement, not in the middle of it when defining a CTE. You don't `SELECT...FROM (WITH {CTE Definition})` it's `WITH {CTE Definition} ... SELECT ...FROM {CTE Name}`. See [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

WITH must be the first keyword of the query. The previous statement must be be terminated by `;` as:

```sql
    ;WITH got_debit_custno (custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno)  as
    (
        select  custno, slipno, category, donation
        ,   case
              when category = 'CREDIT'
              then 'N/A'
              else custno
            end
        from    a
    )
    ,  prep (custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno, rn, rdt) as
    (
        select  dc.*
        ,   row_number ()  over (partition by debit_custno, category order by donation, slipno)
        ,       sum (donation) over (partition by debit_custno, category order by donation, slipno)
        from    got_debit_custno dc
    )
    ,  r (custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno, rn, rdt, mn) as
    (
        select  custno, slipno, category, donation, debit_custno
        ,       case
                when rn = max(rn) over (partition by debit_custno, category)
                then rn
            end
        ,       rdt, 1
        from    prep
        where   rdt <= 27000 or rn = 1
     union all
        select  p.custno, p.slipno, p.category, p.donation, p.debit_custno
        ,       case
                when p.rn = max(p.rn) over (partition by p.debit_custno, p.category)
                then p.rn
            end
        ,       p.rdt, r.mn + 1
        from    prep p
        join    r    on  p.debit_custno = r.debit_custno
                 and p.category = r.categoRy
                 and p.rn > r.rn
                             and (p.rdt <= r.rdt + 27000 or p.rn = r.rn + 1)
    )
    select    custno, slipno, category, donation
    ,         dense_rank () over (order by debit_custno, category, mn) as unique_nm
    from      r
    order by  custno, unique_nm, donation
```

Comment: _Must be preceeding by ;_ That is simply incorrect. Rather it is a kludge to avoid terminating the prior statement within the same batch. The semi-colon is a statement **terminator**, not a "beginator".

Comment: Yes with must be a first statement i understand, The reason i am asking is i want to put my complete statement in MERGE which is not working that why asking how should i rewrite this to acheive my requirement

Comment: @user15940336 That is a very different question. The one you posted has been answered so please mark it as such. Then do some internet searching first to find discussions about using merge with a CTE. No one but you knows what you are trying to accomplish nor how exactly you plan on using a CTE with a merge statement.